# Ubuntu: Cannot resize/extend pratition using gparted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

Context: Originally I had a dual boot machine, with Windows occupying around 180 GB and Ubuntu occupying 59 GB. However, I decided that I just wanted to use Ubuntu and I didn't need Linux, so I deleted the space for Windows (it's unallocated), and now I end up with the following situation:

[image]

However, when I try to resize Partition /dev/nvme0n1p5, it doesn't allow me to resize it futher. What specific steps should I take?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but what I personally would do is create a backup of `/dev/nvme0n1p5` using Ubuntu's GUI (Disks I believe... it's in the Utilities app launch folder), save the copy to another drive, then reinstall Ubuntu (unless you know how to manually set up the EFI partition) & apply the image - w/o doing so, and if you don't plan on reinstalling Windows on this drive, you're going to be left w/ two orphaned Windows partitions, MSR (likely `p2`) and WinRE (likely `p3`), coupled w/ Windows' boot files still residing within `p1` if Ubuntu used the same EFI partition as Windows.

Comment: You can move the partition to the left and then expand but this is slightly more risky than just expanding.